# Why is the first section indented

Tags: indentation, classicthesis

I have been using LaTeX for a week now,

How come the section title for a plan of investigation and the subsection title, research question aren't aligned with the rest of the document:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\title{History IA}
\author{Kabelo Moiloa}
\date{15 May 2014}
\maketitle

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}

\tableofcontents

\section{Plan of investigation}

\subsection*{Research Question}
\quote "To what extent does the book, Homage to Catalonia accurately portray life under Anarchism in Revolutionary Spain between 1931-1939?"

\section{Method of Investigation}
This investigation evaluates the extent to which George Orwell's Novel, Homage to Catalonia can be used as a reliable historical source in evalating life under Anarchism in Revolutionary Spain. To this end, source evaluation will be used in order to compare Revolutionary Spain as portrayed in Homage to Catalonia to other sources, in particular: Revolution and War in Spain (1931-1939),  Democracy and Civil War in Spain 1931-1939, Spain's Civl War and finally The Battle for Spain.

\section{Summary of Evidence}

\section{Evaluation of Sources}

\section{Analysis}




\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

`quote` is an environment:

```
 \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\title{History IA}
\author{Kabelo Moiloa}
\date{15 May 2014}
\maketitle

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}

\tableofcontents

\section{Plan of investigation}

\subsection*{Research Question}
\begin{quote} "To what extent does the book, Homage to Catalonia accurately portray life under Anarchism in Revolutionary Spain between 1931-1939?"
\end{quote}

\section{Method of Investigation}
This investigation evaluates the extent to which George Orwell's Novel, Homage to Catalonia can be used as a reliable historical source in evalating life under Anarchism in Revolutionary Spain. To this end, source evaluation will be used in order to compare Revolutionary Spain as portrayed in Homage to Catalonia to other sources, in particular: Revolution and War in Spain (1931-1939),  Democracy and Civil War in Spain 1931-1939, Spain's Civl War and finally The Battle for Spain.

\section{Summary of Evidence}

\section{Evaluation of Sources}

\section{Analysis}




\pagebreak

\end{document}
```